# Python prints wrong encoding from MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, utf-8, pymssql

I'm having issues with my Python when calling data from my MySQL database.

The database is set as UTF-8 and is containing, special letters such as 'Æ' and 'Ø'.

This is the code i use to call the Usernames from my Table

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import pymysql
db = pymysql.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="XXXXXXXX",
    db="pythonconnectiontest", 
    charset="utf8"
)
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT Username FROM Account")

numrows = cursor.rowcount 
for i in range (numrows):
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    print row
```

The expected output is:

```
ThisTextIsBrøken
Tæst 
Word
```

Actual output:

```
(u'ThisTextIsBr\xf8ken',)
(u'T\xe6st',)
(u'Word',)
```

I do get that the 'U' in front of the value, indicates that this is UNICODE and i probably just need to make python interpret the text correctly with encode() or decode().

I've spent many hours trying to figure this out, and the solution is probably very simple.

I hope someone can help me fix this.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Can you try use `print unicode(row)` it might solve your problem

Comment: Didn't have any effect on the output data, unfortunately.

Comment: Please provide `SELECT HEX(col), col FROM ...`  If 'Tæst' comes out `54657374`, then you _really_ have latin1 encoding in the table!  If everything is utf8, then the hex will be `54C3A67374`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unicode strings it's outputting are perfectly fine. You can verify this by trying `print u'ThisTextIsBr\xf8ken'` in a python shell:

```py
➜ python2
Python 2.7.15 (default, Jan 10 2019, 23:20:52)
[GCC 8.2.1 20181127] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print u'ThisTextIsBr\xf8ken'
ThisTextIsBrøken
```

Your confusion is merely about how python represents unicode strings that are wrapped in another object. In this case your rows each represent a `tuple` of columns or more specifically a tuple containing a single unicode string.

You can verify this by adjusting your code to print the actual unicode string rather than the tuple containing it.

```py
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import pymysql
db = pymysql.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="XXXXXXXX",
    db="pythonconnectiontest", 
    charset="utf8"
)
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT Username FROM Account")

numrows = cursor.rowcount 
for i in range (numrows):
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    print row[0]
```

This should now output the expected strings.